# Not receive any webhook events from Paypal sandbox account

Tags: paypal-sandbox

Like the title says,
I followed the same set up with this article, created both personal test account and business test account, subscribed all* events for webhook URL.

Webhook URL working fine with simulator but not work on the real transaction in sandbox environment.
After deeper investigation, We found out that there were no transaction records inside Sandbox Transactions section, but all passed transaction have been tracked down inside Notification section, which mean that we did make an successful transaction to PayPal.

I assume that webhook event tie with the transaction record, if there is no transaction been found in paypal we will never get out webhook event. 
So, someone please teach me how to do a proper setup for sandbox account to get our webhooks.

[No transactions and webhook events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76r1p.jpg)

[All successful payments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUw1V.jpg)